# Linear dependency between 2 categorical variables in multiple regression

Tags: r, regression, multiple-regression

I am trying to run a backward selection in R and to build predictive model for car price (using [this car dataset](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Automobile)). I can't figure out how to deal with cat. vars fueltype- gas/diesel and fuelsystem- mpfi,2bbl,idi,etc. The thing is, only diesel cars use idi fuelsystem and viceversa. This results in getting NA in my model summary for either fueltype factor or fuelsystem idi. I also get message there is a singularity.
How do I solve this problem? Should I make 2 different models for each type of fuel? Or is there an easier solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regression covariates cannot be linearly dependent. The nested categorical variables are an example of just such a case. That is also the reason for the singularity. If you focus on the interpretation of categorical effects, you can either recode the variables and/or alter the variable selection process. Naïvely adjusting fuel type and delivery method, only one level of the delivery method is coded to referent, presumably multipoint fuel injection. As such there is no categorical effect for this level. You can additionally drop a referent diesel fueling method, like direct injection, so that the contrasts are specific to the fuel type. As a warning, recoded fuel delivery makes no sense unless fuel type is adjusted in the model, so dependencies must be implemented in model selection. Also a warning: forward/backward model selection is wholly discredited by statisticians any more. Much better predictive models are developed based on modern methods like the BIC.